# Импорт TS файлов из npm модуля

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, импорт, микросервисы

Возникла потребность разбить TS проект на несколько репозиториев/пакетов, и из различных их комбинаций строить микросервисы. Какие-то пакеты нужны в одном микросервисе, какие-то в другом, какие-то во всех.

При деплое код компиллируется и исполняются JS файлы (естесственно).

Но теперь получается, что если в подключаемом пакете просто из TS файла экспортировать какой-то код, то при исполнении скомпиллированного микросервиса возникает ошибка, т.к. код микросервиса пытается что-то импортировать из внешней библиотеки и не находит JS файла с таким содержанием.

И для корректной работы такой системы мне нужно не просто вносить изменения в TS код подключаемых пакетов, но и билдить их, пушить в репозиторий скомпиллированный код и публиковать npm пакет так же включающий этот скомпиллированный код.
Что неудобно, выглядит странно, и еще про это легко забыть.

Есть ли способ организовать репозитории/npm пакеты таким образом, чтобы публиковать (и следить за актуальностью) только TS код, а при компилляции микросервиса из импорта вытягивался TS код и JavaScript генерился бы один раз в одном месте при деплое?

Comment: ну а самое главное-то где? чем происходит сборка что такое деплой (здесь)? твой вопрос в одну строчку: "Как при сборке проекта webpack (замени на свой) компилировать модули?". Всё!

Comment: @qwabra возможно я сформулировал вопрос недостаточно точно. на самом деле вопрос я задал достаточно давно, а сейчас вновь столкнулся с этой проблемой. попробую задать его более точно: как сделать так, чтобы в репозитории у меня лежал только ts код, и следил бы я только за актуальностью ts кода, и наверно даже папка dist была благополучно добавлена в gitignore, по при этом человек мог бы поставить мой пакет через npm и подключить зависимость (а в рантайме подключается js код) и у него бы все взлетело

Comment: разработчики nest.js и curveball как то это делают черт возьми

Comment: чем происходит сборка

Comment: @qwabra сборка происходит коммандой tsc

Comment: ммм, бэк, нода? commonjs или бандл? tsconfig покажи пж. хотяяяя, хммммм ....

Comment: небольшое уточнение, это для себя/команды или для нуу, например опенсорс проекта

Comment: и ещё, отказ от использования сторонних сборщиков принципиален? или рассматриваются любые варианты?

Comment: @qwabra по поводу бэка и ноды - я думал я указал исчерпывающие теги к вопросу

Comment: @qwabra по поводу отказа от всяких вебпаков - на бэке это не имеет смысла, там незачем бандлить и минифицировать

Comment: @qwabra по поводу назначения - в первый раз у меня возник этот вопрос на рабочем проекте. сейчас этот вопрос у меня возник опять, когда я захотел опубликовать свой npm пакет. и я решил привлечь внимание к вопросу.

Comment: @qwabra по поводу ts конфига. да могу показать если очень интересно, но к вопросу это не имеет отношение. по поводу рассмотрения любых вариантов - рассматриваются любые варианты)) какая разница какой командой и с вызовом каких инструментов проводить билд. вопрос то в том - что можно сделать, чтобы можно было добавить папку dist в gitignore, а у пользователей всё импортировалось бы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо способов много. Я пока для себя придумал следующий. Прикрутил github actions на автоматическую сборку и закидывание в npm при пуше в мастер. Надо бы еще доработать чтобы все это происходило только если версия поменялась, но уже спать хочется (да и так сработает, т.к. если версия не поменялась то паблиш с ошибкой упадет, просто пайплайн долго крутиться будет).

Вот первая версия yaml файла для экшена:

```
name: npm-publish

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  npm-publish:
    name: npm-publish
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Set up Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@master
      with:
        node-version: 12
        registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/

    - name: Remove a dist folder from gitignore
      run: sed -i '$ d' .gitignore

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm i

    - name: Build
      run: npm run build

    - name: Publish
      run: npm publish
      env:
        NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_AUTH_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: собственно с результатом можно ознакомиться здесь: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastify-react-views в репозитории нет js кода, но если пакет установить в ваш проект, то в рантайме все хорошо подключается

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли способ организовать репозитории/npm пакеты таким образом, чтобы публиковать (и следить за актуальностью) только ts код, а при компилляции микросервиса из импорта вытягивался ts код и джаваскрипт генерился бы один раз в одном месте при деплое?

Конечно есть, вы можете в пакет положить что угодно, хоть фотки вашей собаки в детстве, хоть исполняемые файлы. Вопрос зачем?

`npm` пакет - это некий готовый к использованию код, который уже собран и не требует дополнительных действий для использования. Достаточно импортировать/подключить его и все готово. Если же вы положите в пакет только `ts` то при использовании придется обязательно иметь компиляцию `ts`, а если в проекте не используется `ts`? Получится оверхед ради одного пакета.

> И для корректной работы такой системы мне нужно не просто вносить
>   изменения в ts код подключаемых пакетов, но и билдить их, пушить в
>   репозиторий скомпиллированный код и публиковать npm пакет так же
>   включающий этот скомпиллированный код.

А вы как именно тестируете код, который написали в рамках самого пакета? Почему сборка `ts > js` выглядит странной? У `ts` есть параметр `watch` которые сразу же перекомпилирует файлы, когда они поменялись + еще и типы сбилдит.  Поэтому сразу же при написании кода у вас будет собираться готовый `js` в папочке `dist`.

> публиковать npm пакет так же включающий этот скомпиллированный код

Пакеты не обязательно публиковать, можно ставить через [`file:path/to/local/module`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38417065/5703133). Тогда все что нужно будет сделать, это переустановить пакет

```
rm -rf nodu_modules && npm install local_module
// либо обновить версию пакета и запустить
npm update
```

Добавьте компиляцию `ts` в `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "ts-build": "ts --watch"
}
```

А дальше, там где нужно подключить пакет используете локальный путь

```
"dependencies": {
  "local_module": "file:path/to/module"
}
```

Что бы ваш пакет воспринимался как `ts` можно воспользоваться сборкой типов + полем [`types`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html) в `package.json`

Comment: пакет мне нужно публиковать, потому что я хочу распространять свою либу, а npm чертовски удобная платформа для этого. довольно странно будет выглядеть если я всем буду нахваливать свою опенсурс либу и давать ссылку на зип архив с кодом.

Comment: про ts --watch - моя проблема не в тестировании или локальном запуске. я не хочу в репозитории держать собранный код - довольно легко (как выяснилось) запушить коммит с измененным ts кодом и забыть запушить свежесобранный js. если вы посмотрите в репозитории nest.js или curveball, то не найдете там js файлов либо папки dist. однако после установки npm пакета в node_modules оказываются js файлы которые прекрасно импортируются в рантайме. видимо мне сразу с вопросами нужно было писать на мыло разработчикам этих пакетов.

Comment: @muturgan понятно, смотрите есть разница между гитом ( как пример ) и npm. В гит пушится одно, в npm выкладывается другое и это нормальная практика). В гит - сорсы для разработки, в npm готовый код)

Comment: и если вы хотите выкладывать свой код в общий доступ, при этом оставляя только `ts`, то я, не используя `ts`, не смогу воспользоваться вашей библиотекой(

Answer (score 1):

В `package.json` надо указать

```
"main": "some-file.ts",
```

тогда при установке пакета и иморте из него будет использоваться код на typescript'е. При этом держать в репозитории скомпилированный код вообще не потребуется (впрочем, стоит убедиться в одинаковости версии тайпскрипта между проектами).

Чтобы запустить тайпскриптовый код можно использовать [`tsnode`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) (если речь идёт о бэкенде). В случае же с webpack'ом только непосредственно вебпаковский проект будет компилироваться в js, а все зависимости себе он будет подтаскивать в виде ts и перекомпилировать сам.